# Backbone class selector for only 1 class

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have two `<a>` tags. One with class:

```
table-link
```

other:

```
table-link danger
```

In my backbone view's events, I want to trigger each with a callback:

```
events: {
    'click .table-link': 'edit',
    'click .table-link.danger': 'del'
}
```

This works fine for `table-link`, however, when `table-link danger` is clicked, it calls both `del` and `edit`

How can I make latter not trigger `.table-link` clicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible I'd suggesting making the 'edit' binding explicit by adding '.edit' to the table link elements and changing your code:

```
events: {
    'click .table-link.edit': 'edit',
    'click .table-link.danger': 'del'
}
```

This makes it clearer and easier imo to add new table-link types in the future.

Comment: 1+.. Agreed. This does make it clearer and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to exclude it:

```
events: {
    'click .table-link:not(.danger)': 'edit',
    'click .table-link.danger': 'del'
}
```

I'd suggest adding an additional class to the element, as [stealthwang suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880750/2680216), though.